# How can I make a Humanoid killable, and have it respawn? (Roblox)

Tags: roblox

Title. All tutorials I have found only explain how to make a human model, not how to make it killable. i have set the humanoid's Health and Max health to 100, and it's showing the health bar, but it cannot take damage.
Thanks!

Comment: Huh? Players / Humanoids are automatically kill-able by default.

Comment: How are you attempting to cause damage to it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the humanoid is taking damage from. If it is taking damage from a LocalScript that does not support FE, then, the Humanoid would not take damage.

If you want to make a Humanoid take damage, or kill it instantly, here are some methods:

**Killing instantly** (from a non - LocalScript)

```
local character = nil; -- replace nil with the character
character:BreakJoints();
```

**Killing instantly** (from a LocalScript)

*In a local script:*

```
local character = game:service("Players").LocalPlayer.Character -- replace this to the character. if you don't replace it, it will kill your character.
local rep = game:service("ReplicatedStorage");
local event = rep:WaitForChild("killEvent");

event:FireServer(character);
```

*In a normal script:*

```
local rep = game:service("ReplicatedStorage");
local ev = Instance.new("RemoteEvent",rep);
ev.Name = "killEvent";

ev.OnServerEvent:connect(function(plr, char)
    if not char then char = plr.Character end;
    char:BreakJoints();
end);
```

**Taking a amount of damage** (from a non - LocalScript)

```
local character = nil; -- replace nil with the character
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid");
local damage = 50; -- Change this to the damage you want the humanoid to take

humanoid:TakeDamage(damage);
```

**Taking a amount of damage** (from a LocalScript)

*In a local script:*

```
local rep = game:service("ReplicatedStorage");
local event = rep:WaitForChild("damageEvent");

local character = game:service("Players").LocalPlayer.Character; -- replace this to the character. if you don't change it, it will automatically damage your character.

local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid");

local damage = 50; -- Change this to the damage you want the player to take

event:FireServer(humanoid, damage);
```

*In a normal script:*

```
local rep = game:service("ReplicatedStorage");

local event = Instance.new("RemoteEvent", rep);
event.Name = "damageEvent";
event.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player, hum, damage)
    if not hum then hum = player.Character.Humanoid; end;
    hum:TakeDamage(damage);
end);
```

That should do it for making a Humanoid take damage or to kill it. You can also use these methods to kill other players, since we use Remotes for locals.

Hope my answer helps!